# NetSuite RESTlet not returning Purchase Order records via Saved Search

Tags: netsuite, restlet

We have a transaction based Saved Search which is pulls Puchase Order data:

```
Criteria: 
Type is Purchase Order
Date is on yesterday
```

When run manually it outputs around 20 records so the search is returning records.  However when I access the saved search from within a RESTlet it returns zero records and the 'data' object is empty.  If I alter the criteria of the Saved Search so that 'Type is Sales Order' it returns about 100 records so it seems that either there is a restriction on returning Purchase Order data via scripting or that I'm accessing it incorrectly.

Any ideas?
Here is my script (SuiteScript 1.0)

```
function getRESTlet(dataIn) {

    var message = "";
    var status = "OK";
    var data = {};

    var savedSearch = nlapiLoadSearch('transaction', 'customsearch_maximum_rdc');
    var resultset = savedSearch.runSearch();
    var returnSearchResults = [];
    var searchid = 0;
    do {
        var resultslice = resultset.getResults(searchid, searchid + 1000);
        for (var rs in resultslice) {
            returnSearchResults.push(resultslice[rs]);
            searchid++;
        }
    } while (resultslice.length >= 1000);

    var results = {"count":searchid, "data":returnSearchResults};
    return results;

} // Close function
```

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue.  Are you executing the RESTlet from the internal or external URL?  What role are you using?  Does the role have the necessary permissions for accessing purchase orders?  Note that if you're using the external URL the role used will (likely) be different from what you're logged in with.

Comment: You're spot on!  It was a permissions issue and adding Purchase Order global permissions was enough to read the data.  Thanks!